# Pool of Thread Pools

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, delegates

I had a problem at my work that we have some tasks that need to be executed as fast as possible. To do this we implemented them so they are multi-threaded in an ExecutorService. Originally we had for each different type of task a different ExecutorService (simple Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpuCount)).
However, these tasks only come in very short bursts that might have a bunch of time between them. So instead of having all threads running at the same time, we wanted them to timeout. Also, it is very unlikely that different types of tasks are running at the same time.

The solution that I came up with was implementing my own AbstractExecutorService that delegates the work to a pool of ThreadPools so that they can time out and also you have a minimum amount of idle Threads. Please give me feedback on the concept, the implementation, coding style, comments and anything else you can think of.

````java
package com.anon.exec;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;

/**
 * This is a utility class to have a pool of thread pools.
 * It is used so that you can have the minimal number of threads running at the same time while at the same time providing multiple thread pools with equal priority
 * so that tasks scheduled together are similarly finished instead of having to wait for unrelated tasks.
 *
 * The class is designed to time out the threads in the thread pool.
 */
public class ThreadPoolPool extends AbstractExecutorService {

    private final List<ThreadPoolExecutor> internalExecutors;

    /**
     * Create a new pool of Thread Pools. You can specify the number of pools and the number of threads per pool.
     * @param poolCount the number of pools to create
     * @param poolSize the number of threads per pool
     * @param nameScheme this name is appended to the front of the thread name
     * @param threadTimeout how long until the thread times out
     * @param threadTimeoutUnit what unit the threadTimeout is in
     */
    public ThreadPoolPool(final int poolCount, final int poolSize, String nameScheme, final long threadTimeout, final TimeUnit threadTimeoutUnit) {
        if (poolCount < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("poolCount must be at least 1");
        }
        if (poolSize < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("poolSize must be at least 1");
        }
        if (nameScheme == null) {
            nameScheme = "ThreadPoolPool-" + hashCode();
        }
        if (threadTimeout < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("threadTimeout must be at least 1");
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(threadTimeoutUnit, "threadTimeoutUnit must not be null");

        this.internalExecutors = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(poolCount));
        for (int i = 0; i < poolCount; i++) {
            final ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(nameScheme + "-pool-" + i + "-thread-%d").build();
            ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize, threadTimeout, threadTimeoutUnit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), factory);
            exec.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
            this.internalExecutors.add(exec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor pool : this.internalExecutors) {
                pool.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            return this.internalExecutors.stream().map(ExecutorService::shutdownNow).flatMap(List::stream).collect(toList());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShutdown() {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor pool : this.internalExecutors) {
                if (!pool.isShutdown()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTerminated() {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor pool : this.internalExecutors) {
                if (!pool.isTerminated()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean awaitTermination(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor pool : this.internalExecutors) {
                if (!pool.awaitTermination(timeout, unit)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final Runnable command) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getAvailableExecutor(1);
        exec.execute(command);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T invokeAny(final Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getAvailableExecutor(tasks.size());
        return exec.invokeAny(tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T invokeAny(final Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getAvailableExecutor(tasks.size());
        return exec.invokeAny(tasks, timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(final Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getAvailableExecutor(tasks.size());
        return exec.invokeAll(tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(final Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getAvailableExecutor(tasks.size());
        return exec.invokeAll(tasks, timeout, unit);
    }

    /**
     * Finds an executor that can execute the given number of tasks. If there isn't one that can fit all tasks, the executor with the smallest current number of active tasks is returned.
     * @param taskCount the number of tasks you want to execute
     * @return a executor to execute your tasks
     */
    public ThreadPoolExecutor getAvailableExecutor(final int taskCount) {
        synchronized (this.internalExecutors) {
            int minActiveCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            ThreadPoolExecutor minPool = null;
            for (ThreadPoolExecutor pool : this.internalExecutors) {
                int activeCount = pool.getActiveCount();
                if (activeCount < minActiveCount) {
                    minPool = pool;
                    minActiveCount = activeCount;
                }
                if (activeCount + taskCount < pool.getMaximumPoolSize()) {
                    return pool;
                }
            }
            if (minPool != null) {
                return minPool;
            }
            else {
                return this.internalExecutors.stream().findAny() // we check in the constructor that we have at least one executor
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("ThreadPoolPool has no Executors, this is an illegal state"));
            }
        }
    }

}

```
````

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think this code is readable and comprehensible. I don't have many complaints

That said, `awaitTermination` waits sequentially for each sub-pool in turn - that means if you have many pools you might be waiting for several times as long as the timeout specified. If the caller says to wait for up to `100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` then *each* of our pools could make us wait for 99 ms before it finishes and we'd still claim we finished before timing out - but if we have 200 pools we'd do so after having blocked for almost 20 seconds, even though we should've timed out much sooner than that. That doesn't seem ideal

Additionally, `getAvailableExecutor` feels internal enough that I wonder if it really should be `public`? No other public method exposes any of the sub-pools, it feels weird that this one does

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree with getAvailableExecutor, in the end it turned out I didn't need this. I think I had this in the past because I needed some method from the ThreadPoolExecutor class.
For the awaitTermination, I didn't realize this, but looking at it now, yeah that could be a big problem. Do you think maybe I should multithread the awaittermination for the internalExecutors? Or should I just divide the timeout by the number of internalExecutors? I'm not sure what's better here.

Comment: @Skrelp I'm not sure either. Dividing the timeout could run into issues if one pool needs a lot more time than the others (maybe it'll finish before the timeout passes but not before 1/10th of the timeout passes, which would mean the order of the pools matters), but having threads whose only job is to wait for other threads feels... awkward

Comment: @Skrelp Could it be possible for the internal executors to somehow inform the pool-pool when they terminate? Perhaps the pool-pool could have a `Semaphore` with `poolCount` permits, with each internal executor taking a permit when they start working and releasing it in an overridden `ThreadPoolExecutor::terminate`? Then `ThreadPoolPool::awaitTermination` could be built using something like `this.semaphore.tryAcquire(this.internalExecutors.size(), timeout, unit)`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the requirements it's not clear to me why "instead of having all threads running at the same time, we wanted them to timeout."

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to implement rate limiting on an executor. It could be used to optimize throughput and mitigate noisy neighbors running on the same machine.

There are different design choices for APIs. For `execute()` you can choose what to do with excess tasks: put them in a queue, block the calling code, or reject. This really depends on the use case and context.

I suggest taking a look at Guava's [RateLimiter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java) and Java [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Since this is the code review site could you take a stab at some meaningful observations about the code itself. You have already made meaningful observations about the design.